# Cordova: push notification when device is offline iOS and Android

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins

My app needs to send "push notification" even if:

1) the App is not running or it's in background

2) the device is offline

Notifiation service works fine when the device is online and I can contact the phone.

I need to send a Push notification on the screen even if the device is offline.

Can you suggest me a good solution for Android and iOS?

PS: I know I need a different tool and I can't use notification standard service.
Which tool do you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: if the phone is offline you can't get push notifications, push notifications are sent by a server

Comment: It appears to me you have confused *task* with *tool*. Can you state why you need a "notification" offline?

Comment: Yes, I confused tasks and tools! I'm sorry.

I need to alert user when he is offline to help him during his job. In Italy we are offline very often but we need alerts too

Comment: Hey man, can I ask you if you found a solution to your problem ? 
I have the same issue.

Comment: I remember I found a module for "local notifications". I don't remember its name but I just found this on google!
http://www.sitepoint.com/integrating-local-notifications-in-cordova-apps/